# How to raise event on a mocked object in VB.NET with Rhino Mocks

Tags: vb.net, events, mocking, rhino-mocks

I know how to do it in C#: (from the [docs](http://www.ayende.com/Wiki/Rhino+Mocks+3.5.ashx#Howtoraiseevents))

```
view.Raise(x => x.Load += null, this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

I tried the following:

```
Me.MockObject.Raise(Sub(x) x.SomeEvent(), someArgs)

'Compiler Error: 
'SomeEvent is an event, and cannot be called directly.
'Use a RaiseEvent statement to raise an event.
```

I tried replacing `Sub(x)` with `Function(x)`... no luck either. So tried:

```
Me.MockObject.Raise(Sub(x) x.SomeEvent(), someArgs)

'Compiler Error
'x is not an event of MyTestFixtureClass
```

Oops...

I can't seem to figure it out in VB.NET... any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was almost there... here's what works:

```
Me.MockObject.Raise(Sub(x) AddHandler x.SomeEvent, Nothing, someArgs)
```

Not sure why I'm adding `Nothing` as the eventhandler for the event, the internal mechanics of all this is beyond me.